# Why is the asnyc/await function not been waited?

Tags: next.js, async-await, cloudinary

I am doing an Image Upload feature with Cloudinary. I'm providing an **array** which may contains base64coded or uploaded image which is a url :

```
[
"https://res.cloudinary.com/\[userName\]/image/upload/v167xxxx4/luxxxfsgasxxxxxx7t9.jpg", "https://res.cloudinary.com/doeejabc9/image/upload/v1675361225/rf6adyht6jfx10vuzjva.jpg",
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAUSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAA.......", "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAUSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAA......."
]
```

I'm using this function to upload the "un-uploaded", which returns the all uploaded version:

```
export async function uploadImage(el: string[]) {
  const partition = el.reduce(
    (result: string[][], element: string) => {
      element.includes("data:image/")
        ? result[0].push(element)
        : result[1].push(element);

      return result;
    },
    [[], []]
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < partition[0].length; i++) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", partition[0][i]);
    data.append("upload_preset", "my_preset_name");
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/userName/image/upload",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }
    );
    const file = await res.json();
    partition[1].push(file.secure_url);
    console.log(partition[1]);
  }

  return partition[1];
}
```

Then I will use the return value to update the state and call the api to update database:

```
const uploaded = await uploadImage(el[1])
console.log(uploaded);
setFinalVersionDoc({
          ...chosenDocument,
          [chosenDocument[el[0]]]: uploaded,
        });
```

However, it always updates the useState before the console.log(uploaded). I thought async/await would make sure the value is updated before moving on.

The GitHub repo is attached for better picture. The fragment is under EditModal in the 'component/document' folder:

https://github.com/anthonychan1211/cms

Thanks a lot!

I am hoping to make the upload happen before updating the state.

Comment: The link to the repo doesn't work. Is the repo private? You need to make it public, or post a code snippet here. The most important part is the context of the second snipped you posted. The function you posted is async so it will be awaited, but only if called within the scope of an async function

Comment: @maxeth I'm sorry! It is public now. Thank you so much! The 'uploadImage' function is under 'util/handler' line 274.

Comment: where is the second code snipped being called? Is it called inside an async function? I think that's where the problem is located

Comment: It is called in EditModal in line 205, under 'component/Document'.

Comment: you should add that code-snipped of your handleEdit function i posted below to your original post, because its the only relevant code-snippet for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is correct, but you are trying to await the promise inside the callback function of a `forEach`, but `await` inside `forEach` doesn't work.

### This doesn't work:

```js
async function handleEdit() {
    const entries = Object.entries(chosenDocument);
    entries.forEach(async (el) => { // <------ the problem
      if (Array.isArray(el[1])) {
        const uploaded = await uploadImage(el[1]);
        el[1].splice(0, el[1].length, uploaded);
      }
    });

[...]

}
```

If you want to have the same behaviour (forEach runs **sequentially**), you can use a `for const of` loop instead.

### This works (sequentially)

(execution order guaranteed)

```js
  async function handleEdit() {
  const entries = Object.entries(chosenDocument);
  for (const el of entries) {
      // await the promises 1,2,...,n in sequence 
      if (Array.isArray(el[1])) {
        const uploaded = await uploadImage(el[1]);
        el[1].splice(0, el[1].length, uploaded);
      }
  }
}
```

### This also works (in parallel)

(execution order not guaranteed)

```js
async function handleEdit() {
    const entries = Object.entries(chosenDocument);
    await Promise.all(entries.map(async (el) => {
      // map returns an array of promises, and await Promise.all() then executes them all at the same time
      if (Array.isArray(el[1])) {
        const uploaded = await uploadImage(el[1]);
        el[1].splice(0, el[1].length, uploaded);
      }
    }));

[...]

}
```

If the order in which your files are uploaded doesn't matter, picking the parallel method will be faster/better.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is something I could never find on the internet!